# Hibernate/JPA 2.0 - Table per Class and @EmbeddedId Inheritance

Tags: hibernate, inheritance, jpa-2.0, hibernate-mapping

Aware as I am that `@Embeddable` components inheritance in Hibernate is not supported, I'm trying to find the best strategy to deal with my very custom entity mapping.

The story is as follows:

- I have two tables: `prices_a_b` and `prices_a_b_c`
- I have two entities mapped to each of them: `PriceAB` and `PriceABC`
- Both these tables have compound PKs only that `prices_a_b_c` adds an extra column to the PK

Therefore, this would be the programmatic translation:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public abstract class Price implements Serializable {
  @EmbeddedId
  private AbstractPricePk id;

  public AbstractPricePk getId() {
      return id;
  }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "price_a_b")
@AssociationOverrides(
  { 
    @AssociationOverride(name = "id.a", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "a")),
    @AssociationOverride(name = "id.b", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "b"))
  }
)
public class PriceAB extends Price {
  private PriceABPk id;

  protected PriceAB() {}

  public PriceAB(PriceABPk id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  @Override
  @EmbeddedId
  public PriceABPk getId() {
    return id;
  }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "price_a_b_c")
@AssociationOverrides(
    { 
        @AssociationOverride(name = "id.a", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "a")),
        @AssociationOverride(name = "id.b", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "b")),
        @AssociationOverride(name = "id.c", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "c"))
    }
)
public class PriceABC extends Price {
    private PriceABCPk id;

    protected PriceABC() {}

    public PriceABC(PriceABCPk id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    @EmbeddedId
    public PriceABCPk getId() {
      return id;
    }
}
```

And here are the PKs model:

```
public interface PricePk extends Serializable {
    public A getA();
    public B getB();
}

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractPricePk implements PricePK {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "a")
    private A a;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "b")
    private B b;

    protected AbstractPricePK() { }

    public AbstractPricePK(A a, B b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public A getA() {
        return this.a; 
    }

    public void setA(A a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

    public B getB() {
        return b;
    }

    public void setB(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}

@Embeddable
public class PriceABPk extends AbstractPricePk {

    public PriceABk(A a, B b) {
        super(a,b);
    }
}

@Embeddable
public class PriceABCPk extends AbstractPricePk {
    @ManyToOne
    private C c;

    public PriceABCPk(A a, B b, C c) {
        super(a, b);
        this.c = c;
    }

    public C getC() {
        return b;  
    }

    public void setC(C c) {
        this.c = c;
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting:

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: PriceABPk must not have @Id properties when used as an @EmbeddedId: PriceAB.id
```

Now, the idea behind all of this is that I want to have a `PriceService` that can query both tables and return a `Price` object. Later on, if I need to retrieve `C` from `PriceABC` I can just do an `instanceof`, but most of the time I need to perform the same operations on both types of `Price` objects. Likewise, I'd like to have a `PriceDao`that would create `Price` objects depending on the object I pass as a parameter.

What strategy do you guys think it'd suit best?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a 'hack' by replacing inheritance with composition in your @EmbeddedId

```
@Table (name="prices_a_b")
public class PriceAB extends Price {

    @EmbeddedId
    private PriceABId id;

    // getters/setters etc.
}

@Table (name="prices_a_b_c")
public class PriceABC extends Price {   
    @EmbeddedId
    private PriceABCId id;

    @Embeddable 
    class PriceABCId implements Serializable {
            private PriceABId id;

            @Column(name="COLUMN_C")
            private C additionalPkPropertyC;
    }
}

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Price {
    //all common properties go here
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Great thinking! I could just make `PriceABCId` *require* a `PriceABId`. I will give it a shot :)
But then, if I mark `Price` as `@MappedSuperclass` and I want to have a `PriceDao` I will need to programmatically query one table or the other; in other words, I cannot let Hibernate resolve the proper table as `Price` won't be an `@Entity`... am I correct?

Comment: Also, I would like to add that with the suggested approach all my `@AssociationOverrides` fail

Comment: >> But then, if I mark Price as @MappedSuperclass and I want to have a PriceDao I will need to programmatically query one table or the other <<

Yes, but this can be easily handled in such way e.g.:
session.get(priceObj.getClass(), priceObj.getId());